Merge two audio frames from two streams in real time using PyAV and aiortc MediaStreamTrack
I'm trying to merge multiple audio streams from several WebRTC connections to create a single audio output (and, eventually, get an audio transcript out of it).
I am using aiortc to get the audio streams, I am using PyAV to access audio processing features.
Here is a simplified version of my current code:
class AudioRecorder:
    _task = None
    _container = None
    _audio_stream = None
    _tracks: list[rtcrtpreceiver.RemoteStreamTrack] = []

    def __init__(self, file_path: str):
        self._container = av.open(file=file_path, format=None, mode="w")
        self._audio_stream = self._container.add_stream("aac")

    def add_track(self, track: rtcrtpreceiver.RemoteStreamTrack):
        self._tracks.append(track)

    async def start(self):
        self._task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._start())

    async def _start(self):
        while True:
            for track in self._tracks:
                frame = await track.recv()

                for packet in self._audio_stream.encode(frame):
                    self._container.mux(packet)

Any suggestion or idea welcome, thanks!

if those audio streams aren't delivered to you with common time base and locked phase (senders aren't drifting but genlocked), you're gonna need something that synchronizes them (to one common time base) by resampling.

I'm struggling to get this done easily unfortunately, thank you for your help tho.
I'm now trying to treat those files separately instead of trying to merge them together.
